# Outdoor plumbing using pex pipe

Tags: water, pipe, pex

I live in Portugal and moved into this house a few weeks ago where the plumbing was renovated by the previous owner using PEX pipe.

The plumbing is all outside of the walls, including before it enters the house, which means a part of it is outdoors, subject to UV light and high thermal differences in winter and summer.

I believe that this is not the right way that the plumbing should be applied or at least a specific type of PEX pipe.

How should I start with this, would it be possible to put it inside the walls? Or a new installation would be needed? I'm trying to have an overall idea before spending thousands on a good plumber.

The images for reference:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Presumably not a freezing climate. You'd want to check the manufacturer's documentation on the specific pipe, regarding sunlight exposure. Pipe suitable for sunlight exposure is trivially available - putting pipes in walls or otherwise inside the building will be a large expense, most likely, given this appears to be masonry construction.

Comment: Stupid question, just to get it out of the way: Are you sure this is household plumbing rather than rain-gitter drainage?

Comment: Where in the world do you live? Plumbing regulations vary by region. What you've shown there would never fly in the US, but might be common where you are.

Comment: Hi @keshlam it is household plumbing, because it's easily checked with what is inside and I talked with previous owner, even what's inside is really bad. But have it exposed outside, anyone can cut the pipes if he wants and it's more subject to exterior issues I guess.

Comment: Hi @FreeMan, I leave in Portugal, even here I don't think this follows regulations I've never seen a stupid thing as this one before, but my area of expertise is not this one.

Comment: Hi @ecnerwal, yes it's masonry construction, I agree that the expense will be big, but what was before was everything inside the walls, who asked for this was just to save money but now there is an ugly piping, and also I don't think that pipe is the most recommendable to be outdoors exposed to sunlight when looking at the reference

Comment: You're "living for a few weeks" in a house. Why is the plumbing your problem if you'll be gone in a few weeks?

Comment: I had that thought as well, @spuck, and inferred that "new owner who has been living there for a few weeks as of now" was the correct interpretation of that statement.

Comment: Hi @spuck sry for the confusing text. I'm in this house less than a month but I might be living here for a long time or even for the rest of life because of inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

No plumbing should be subjected to freezing temperatures, pex is a bit better than metal plumbing pipes to survive freezing.

UV protection is just to keep it covered, dirt/wood will do.

If subjected to freezing temperatures, would bury outside pipes below the frost line and all pipes for inside be done so they are on/in inside walls, not in the outside walls.

Your location matters, but moving/covering pipes/plumbing is just work.  A plumber should not be needed, unless lazy.

Comment: Hi @crip659, where I leave the minimum temperature can go from near 0 and 40 in the summer. About the covering of the pipes, I've never seen pipes in the walls like in this house, both outside and inside.

Comment: Non freezing temps are good.  Would hope they use UV protected pipes, but if there for long term could cover them with almost anything to keep the sun off. bigger pipes cut in half and mounted over would work.  Short term would let the owners worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

I recently attempted to use a small coil of PEX tubing which I had left stored in my shed for a few years. It has been completely ruined by UV exposure. When I flex the tube it makes a crackling sound, and if I bend it far enough that it should begin kinking, instead it snaps like dry spaghetti noodles.

That's just anecdotal evidence of course. Your PEX is not the same brand as mine, and it may have better UV stability. You could test its current condition by choosing a place and time when you can deal with a possible water shutdown and pipe repair, then try striking the PEX with a hammer to see how resilient it is.

Personally, I would not consider relocating this used PEX into the building. I'd replace it with new material. If you'll be hiring a plumber to do the work then there's no question at all: you'll hardly even notice the cost of materials in comparison to the cost of the plumber's labor to install them.